# What is the best way to store and retrieve marshaled object as attribute in db via Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, marshalling

I have gateway_response object that represents a high level ActiveMerchant gateway response. I'd like to hang on to this object in case I need it for any issues in the future.

I'd like to store it in the DB, and have marshaled it as follows. I've overwritten the getter/setter methods to marshal on assignment and unmarshal on retrieval. This seems to work, but I imagine Active Record has a leaner way to do this:

```
  def gateway_response=(r)
   write_attribute(:gateway_response, Marshal.dump(r))
  end
  def gateway_response
    Marshal.load(read_attribute(:gateway_response))
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) method.

```
class Order
  # add a text column called gateway_response in the `orders` table.
  serialize :gateway_response
end
```

Now:

```
order.gateway_response = r
order.save
order.gateway_response # response object
```

Comment: doesn't this use yaml? and will that turn it back into a usable Response object? Methods and all?

Comment: Methods should not be an issue. Its the data that we should be concerned with. In the past I have stored the hash returned in the response notification using this method. You might want to try this in the console and see if it works.